# Cannot drop the table 'dbo.ContractorPicsPaths', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: sql-server

I manually deleted a table in SQL by right clicking and then clicking "`delete`".  Now when I try to update my database, I get an error saying:

> "Cannot drop the table '`dbo.ContractorPicsPaths`', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I realize I probably should not have done a manual deletion and used a command instead.  What can I do so I can update?

Comment: what do you mean by `update my database` ? can you show us the query ?

Comment: Sure.  Again, I am new.  In nuget package manager console, I typed "add-migration".  Then I typed "update-database".  When I do that, I get the following error: "Error Number:3701,State:5,Class:11
Cannot drop the table 'dbo.ContractorPicsPaths', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: not sure what the nuget package is doing but looks like it is trying to drop the table which you must have manually deleted it. Can you re-create that table and try ?

Comment: I tried.  I get this error: Update cannot proceed due to validation errors.  
Please correct the following errors and try again.

SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.ContractorPicsPaths.
SQL71508 :: The model already has an element that has the same name dbo.ContractorPicsPaths.

Comment: then looks like the table existed. And your login does not have the necessary rights required to execute the package

Comment: The table most certainly existed.  The problem is that I deleted it manually and now SQL is looking for it to try to drop it but can't find it because I deleted it.  For what it is worth this is my own project and there would be no one to deny me permissions unless something is set by default.

Comment: Fixed my problem.  Had to delete the last entries from my migration history table in SQL.

Comment: It totally looks like VisualStudio issue. You dropped table in SSMS or simply deleted file from solution? I suppose VS is now trying to perform `drop table` because of table-file deletion from project.

Comment: Yeah, I first deleted the table in SSMS and then in the solution.  When I tried to update in package manager I got the error.  I solved it by deleting my last migration history.  Then it worked.  Don't fully understand why, but I am guessing the program was trying to apply something held over from a prior migration.  I'm pretty green at this.....